# How can I change the “Indexed: Yes (No Duplicates)” constraint in MS Access to “Indexed: Yes (Duplicates OK)” via SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

is there any possibility to change this constraint?

I dropped constraint:
"ALTER TABLE [table] DROP CONSTRAINT constraint1;"
but I cannot add a new constraint with Yes (Duplicates OK).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no longer a constraint. It's just an [index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177891%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```
CREATE INDEX IX_ABC on Table1 (ABC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want an index?

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column_name)
```

Unless you specifically ask that the index be unique, it will allow duplicates.

The index can be created using the query design window or in VBA.